# 単語のベクトル化をしたいがエラー：Errno 36 File name too long

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflowハブよりuniversal-sentence-encoderを使用して単語のベクトル化をしたいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

**ソースコード**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text
import tensorflow as tf

model_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3'
USE = hub.load(model_url)

with open(path_data_txt, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f_r:
    with open(path_data_txt, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_w:
        for line in f_r:
            vec = ','.join(list(map(str, USE(line).numpy().tolist()[0])))
            f_w.write(vec+'\n')
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long:
```

Comment: エラーメッセージにある通りで、`path_data_txt` か `path_data_txt` の値(パス名)が文字列として長すぎるのだと思います。例えば Windows API の場合は [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#maximum-path-length-limitation) に "In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), **the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters**." と記載されていて、最大で 260 文字となっています。この問題については[回避策](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27694470)がある様です。

Comment: @metropolis コメント欄は回答欄ではないです